# Time complexity of one recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

here we have an algorithm

```
T(n) = n-1 + T(i-1) + T(n-i)
T(1) = 1
```

How to calculate it's time complexity?
**i is between 1 and n**

Comment: What is the value of i ?

Comment: @Gor It does not have a value,

Comment: Then the question doesn't have a solution.

Comment: Of course it has @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we should solve it like this

if i = 2 then we have

```
T(n) = n + T(n-2) = Theta(n^2)
```

if i = n/2 then we have

```
T(n) = n-1 + T(n/2 -1) + T(n/2) = Theta(n.logn)
```

then we have upper bound O(n^2) and algorithm is in order of O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

I can recognise this as quick sort algorithm (randomized quick sort).
I am sure the question somehow missed the summation part.

Okay! you can use substitution method over here..check with `O(n^2)`. you will get the idea that `O(n^2)` is the worst case time complexity.

The average case is a bit tricky. Then the pivot can be any element from 1 to n. Then analyse it. Here also you can apply substituin with `T(n)=O(nlogn)`.

Comment: You shouldn't be answering such ill-stated questions; have them fixed before.

Comment: @YvesDaoust.: You thought I was "upvote-hungry" and that's why answered it. Again you are right about answering such question..okay I will keep it in mind. In this case I was confident about the question. I should have fixed it. Anyway thanks for noticing. I am learning too. Keep up the good work.